# Found a way to make a chat but it does not show the messages

Tags: html, chat

So i got this code...

```
<body bgcolor="#000000">
<input id=input></input>
<button id=button>Send!</buton>
<div id=output></div>
<script src=http://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub-3.1.min.js></script>
<script>(function(){
    var input = PUBNUB.$('input')
    ,     button = PUBNUB.$('button')
    ,     output = PUBNUB.$('output')

PUBNUB.subscribe({
    'channel'  :  'test-chat,
    'callback' :   function(message) {
    output.innerHTML = message + '<br>' + output.innerHTML

}
}

PUBNUB.bind( 'mousedown,touchstart', button, function() {
PUBNUB.publish({
'channel' : 'simple-chat'.
'message' : input.value
})
} )
})()</script>
</body>
```

So.... hm... anyone knows how to make this to work i mean once i use this code.... It works like shows the page and stuff but once i click the Send! button it just does not want to work. Also for the script "libary" https://vimeo.com/36385012. Sorry if i lack expirience or  anything else. I am newbie to the html and web coding so please excuse me.

Comment: You are going to need a sysem server.  Do you have one?  A chat cannot be done using pure HTML.

Comment: I have a free hosting way I upload my files to google drive in a public folder and then i use a service called gdriv.es and then make it a real website if that is what you mean?

Comment: No.  If you send a message, how is it going to pop up on another computer?

Comment: That is why I use some kind of service called PubNub just watch the video on vimeo...